# gaffer on games interpolation

Tags: c, matrix, opengl-es, sdl, interpolation

I implemented the gaffer on [games fixed timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) As you can see from here.

```
static int ce_run_game() {
    start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    while (game_running > 0) {
        current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
        frame_time = (current_time - start_time) * 0.0001;
        if (frame_time >= 0.25) frame_time = 0.25;

        start_time = current_time;

        accum += frame_time;
        while (accum >= delta_time) {
            accum -= delta_time;

            ce_fixed_update();
            ce_fixed_render();
            //SDL_Log("accum %f delta %f\n", accum, delta_time);
        }

        const double alpha = accum / delta_time;
        // state = current_state * alpha + prev_state * (1.0 - alpha);
        ce_var_update(alpha);
        ce_var_render(alpha);

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            ce_handle_events(&event);
            if (event.type == SDL_APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND) {
                ce_pause();
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND) {
                ce_resume();
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                switch (event.window.event) {
                    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                        screen_width = event.window.data1;
                        screen_height = event.window.data2;
                        cam_2d_resize(screen_width, screen_height,
                                      default_camera);
                        ce_resize_window(screen_width, screen_height);
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                ce_quit();
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

so now I have two update and two render functions. I have a fixed and variable update. I plan to do all my non essential things in variable update/ render functions.

The variable functions pass in the apha value that I can use to calculate the interpolation, like this

```
state = current_state * alpha + prev_state * (1.0 - alpha);
```

as described in the article above.

I am running into some issues with interpolation now though. In my fixed update function I'll do something like this pseudo code.

```
if(move_righ) {
     previous_x = x;
     x += 10;
}
```

then in the render function set the matrix translation values to the calculated interpolated values.

ex:

```
float inter_x = prev_x * alpha + prev_x * (1.0f - alpha);
float inter_y = prev_y * alpha + prev_y * (1.0f - alpha);

matrix->col3.x = inter_x;
matrix->col3.y = inter_y;
```

The issue could just be that I cannot use interpolated values like this for matrix in which case I'll have to switch to quaternion which does support interpolation but currently not implemented.

Is the problem that I cannot do interpolation like this with matrix components, I am doing opengles 2.0 and shaders.

Comment: You cannot interpolate matrices like this.

Comment: SDL2 has [`SDL_GetPerformanceCounter()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter) nowadays.

Comment: Related: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Comment: You could always half-ass it with a matrix -> quaternion -> [slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) -> matrix round-trip.

Comment: @BDL if you make an answer I'll select it since it's the most correct answer. genpfault I have quaternion but I don't want to use them right now mainly because I cannot debug them as easily as matrices. Once the api is settled with matrices I can change the underlying code from matrices to quaternions but for now I'll have to stick with matrices.